# Ignoring DatatypeConfigurationException when creating new XMLGregorianCalendar

Tags: java, exception, jax-ws

**When creating a new `XMLGregorianCalendar` instance like this, do I really need to handle the `DatatypeConfigurationException` exception, or can I safely suppress it?**

```
try {
    header.setRequestDateTime(
                DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(
                        new GregorianCalendar()));
} catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
    // pass
}
```

My interpretation of [the documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConfigurationException.html) and some rough logic says this wouldn't really throw an exception unless I give it some bad input.  And that cannot be the case in the above example.  Here's what the JavaDocs say about it:

> If the system property specified by [DATATYPEFACTORY_PROPERTY](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeFactory.html#DATATYPEFACTORY_PROPERTY),
>   "javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory", exists, a class with the name of
>   the property's value is instantiated. Any Exception thrown during the
>   instantiation process is wrapped as a
>   [DatatypeConfigurationException](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/DatatypeConfigurationException.html).

Am I right in thinking that I can safely suppress this checked exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exception of type `DatatypeConfigurationException` may happen **only** in the **static method** call

```
DataTypeFatory factory = DataTypeFactory.newInstance();
```

Therefore you have to treat it only **once**. But you should **treat it once**, otherwise you cannot create your XMLGregorianCalendar instances, at all.

To put it clearly the call

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = factory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(new GregorianCalendar());
```

**never** throws a `DatatypeConfigurationException`, thus you don't have to treat it, when creating XML representations of your `GregorianCalendar` instances. - As from the [Java SE API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/) in the latter call only a `NullPointerException` can occur.

Comment: Thanks.  After reading it more carefully, I realize you're right.  The implication is that, yes, it does need to be treated.

Comment: Why would DataTypeFactory.newInstance() throw the DataTypeConfigurationException at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you opress this exception, you will **not** set the header request time. In this respect, yes, it is a **serious exception**. You cannot generate XML representations of your date and time instances.

On the other hand, your program will not *crash*. It is not a *critical VM error*. But you have to deal with it. You will not be able to fix it on runtime. Your **server** and **VM** environment have to be setup accordingly.

Comment: Since I know I'm passing the constructor the value `new GregorianCalendar()`, this exception will never occur.  I believe the only time an exception can happen here is if I pass in bad arguments, which is not the case for `new GregorianCalendar()`.  A similar example: I know that division can raise an exception -- when I divide by zero.  Does that mean I should wrap something like `double PI = 22.0 / 7.0;` in a try/catch?  Although division **may** raise an exception in some cases, I know it will never in this case.